# Visual Studio Code Factory Reset

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I keep getting a error when I debug and run my HTML doc. I don't know how to fix it, so I just want to factory reset everything and start over fresh. Apparently uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't help as I tried...and am still getting the same issue.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
chromewebdata/(index)꞉6545:22:6770
```

I have no idea how to fix this or even what the direct issue is. I've looked online and tried the 'clear out the launch.json', but that didn't work. I have an HTML assignment due in 3 days. I hope someone out there can help me or give me a good HTML program recommendation.

Comment: what platform? also have you tried looking on github for any related issues?

Comment: I have looked at the VSC page on github. Nothing recently popped up with this issue. I'm really just wanted to restart with this program anyway. It said that if I had in general questions, to ask on here,

Comment: I would suggest that you go into launch.json, find the line: "url" :  "http://localhost:8080", and change the port number (8080) to match that of your live server.  If they're already the same, then google "crbug/1173575".  There are quite a few different ways that individuals have resolved this issue.